# How to disable auto creation of db and collection in spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I am working on a spring boot project which uses spring data mongodb. Spring data mongodb auto creates the db and collection when it doesn't exists. I want to disable auto creation of db and collection in mongodb when it doesn't exists.

How to achieve that? Is there any property which can be used?

Comment: The spring boot mongodb library does not have this kind of behaviour. The collections are not created unless a document has been insert or it has explicitly told to do so. What library are you using for mongodb? Do you have any inserts on startup?

Comment: When i am inserting any document, it creates the collection. Is there a way to disable that behaviour?

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Comment: Sorry then I'm not understanding, how can a document be insert in a collection and the collection not being created. Are you inserting a document in collection x and it creates collections x and y or is it creating only collection x? Cause if it's the latter then it's the expected behaviour and there is no way to disable that